# Updating different fields in different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've tried to ask this question at least once, but I never seem to put it across properly. I really have two questions.

My database has a table called PatientCarePlans
( ID, Name, LastReviewed, LastChanged, PatientID, DateStarted, DateEnded). There are many other fields, but these are the most important.

Every hour, a JSON extract gets a fresh copy of the data for PatientCarePlans, which may or may not be different to the existing records. That data is stored temporarily in PatientCarePlansDump. Unlike other tables which will rarely change, and if they do only one or two fields, with this table there are MANY fields which may now be different. Therefore, rather than simply copy the Dump files to the live table based on whether the record already exists or not, my code does the no doubt wrong thing: I empty out any records from PatientCarePlans from that location, and then copy them all from the Dump table back to the live one. Since I don't know whether or not there are any changes, and there are far too many fields to manually check, I must assume that each record is different in some way or another and act accordingly.

My first question is how best (I have OKish basic knowledge, but this is essentially a useful hobby, and therefore have limited technical / theoretical knowledge) do I ensure that there is minimal disruption to the PatientCarePlans table whilst doing so? At present, my code is:

```
IF Object_ID('PatientCarePlans') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
     BEGIN TRANSACTION
     DELETE FROM [PatientCarePlans] WHERE PatientID IN (SELECT PatientID FROM [Patients] WHERE location = @facility)
     COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
ELSE
     SELECT TOP 0 * INTO [PatientCarePlans]
     FROM [PatientCareplansDUMP]

INSERT INTO [PatientCarePlans] SELECT * FROM [PatientCarePlansDump]
    
DROP TABLE [PatientCarePlansDUMP]
```

My second question relates to how this process affects the numerous queries that run on and around the same time as this import. Very often those queries will act as though there are no records in the PatientCarePlans table, which causes obvious problems. I'm vaguely aware of transaction locks etc, but it goes a bit over my head given the hobby status! How can I ensure that a query is executed and results returned whilst this process is taking place? Is there a more efficient or less obstructive method of updating the table, rather than simply removing them and re-adding? I know there are merge and update commands, but none of the examples seem to fit my issue, which only confuses me more!

Apologies for the lack of knowhow, though that of course is why I'm here asking the question.

Thanks

Comment: Columns *not* "fields".

Comment: Like I said, "hobby" not "expert". But thanks for your input.

Comment: You basically need to do the whole thing inside a transaction: delete those rows and re-insert them. To prevent anyone else getting no results while you are doing that, you would either need a full table lock, or use the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level. Either of those options mean anyone else will get blocked waiting when querying and waits until you are finished until they get their results. I would strongly recommend you don't drop or recreate the `PatientCarePlans` as that will significantly complicate matters.

Comment: You could use `MERGE` instead of `DELETE` `INSERT` but note that if you decide to do `MERGE` instead of a `DELETE` `INSERT` combination, you still need `SERIALIZABLE` to ensure your data gets locked correctly

Comment: @Charlieface that’s very useful, thanks very much. Sounds like I’ll need to look chiefly at serializable. I’ll do that now. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @Charlieface. So, if I put a LOCK TABLE [PatientCarePlans] with an exclusive lock to remove and re-insert the records, will that mean that any other queries will just wait until the lock is removed before returning their results?

Comment: Yes, although that does reduce concurrency obviously. If you want other queries to still be able to query other parts of the table then just use `SERIALIZABLE` isolation. But if you will be deleting and reinserting large numbers of rows then either way you will probably get a table lock. The exact syntax would be `FROM PatientCarePlans WITH (TABLOCK)` and you need to do that for each table you want to lock

Comment: @Charlieface great, thanks so much. I'm far from stupid, but sometimes when you don't have the technical background or experience, stuff on the net can be a bit confusing / jargon-y to an amateur who just needs to solve a problem! I'll give it a try. Cheers.

Comment: @Charlieface that certainly looks to have done the trick. Thanks. If you want to get the "answer" for this, please put it into a proper reply and I'll be more than happy to accept it as the answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do not delete and re-create the table. The DDL script to create the table should be part of your database setup, not part of regular modification scripts.

You are going to want to do the `DELETE` and `INSERT` inside a transaction. Preferably you would do this under `SERIALIZABLE` isolation in order to prevent concurrency issues. (You could instead do a `WITH (TABLOCK)` hint, which would be less likely cause a deadlock, but will completely lock the table.)

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;  -- always set XACT_ABORT if you have a transaction
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT;

BEGIN TRAN;

DELETE FROM [PatientCarePlans]
WHERE PatientID IN (
    SELECT p.PatientID
    FROM [Patients] p
    WHERE location = @facility
);

INSERT INTO [PatientCarePlans] (YourColumnsHere)  -- always specify columns
SELECT YourColumnsHere
FROM [PatientCarePlansDump];

COMMIT;
```

You could also do this with a single `MERGE` statement. However it is complex to write (owing to the need to restrict the set of rows being targetted), and is not usually more performant than separate statements, and also needs `SERIALIZABLE`.